Where to locate AWS instance profile data to make the relevant roles show up in the EC2 instance?
I am trying to add a role to an EC2 instance in AWS but the role doesn't show up. Then I saw that in AWS troubleshooting it says "If the IAM roles and instance profiles have different names, then make sure that you select the correct instance profile". But I can't find the instance profile data. How do I do this?
I want to add a selected role to an EC2 instance.

You should just be able to assign the IAM Role to the instance. All the "instance profile" stuff is handled behind-the-scenes. Can you tell us how you "add a role to an EC2 instance"? Was the IAM Role created for the EC2 service? (You can check the Trust Policy to see if this is the case.)

Navigate to IAM console, click on Roles
Then find the role you want to use and click on it.
Navigate to the Trust Relationships tab on the Role Details page.
Please choose EC2 as a trusted entity.
need to create the instance profile if it does not already exist
